# How to automatically kill slow MongoDB queries?

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

Is there a way that I can protect my app against slow queries in MongoDB?
My application has tons of possibilities of filters and I'm monitoring all these queries but at the same time I don't want to compromise performance because of a missing index definition.

Comment: It is possible to prohibit queries that don't use indexes. To do this, configure MongoDB with `notablescan` option set to `true`.

Comment: I realize that none of the answers below are particularly satisfying, since it doesn't seem that there is currently a way to do this, but it is considered polite to accept an answer, even if that answer is "you can't do that (yet)".

Comment: @acm with 2.6 there is a way to do this. You can check my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The 'notablescan' option, as @ghik mentioned, will prevent you from running queries that are slow due to not using an index. However, that option is global to the server, and it is not appropriate for use in a production environment. It also won't protect you from any other source of slow queries besides table scans.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to directly do what you want right now. There is a JIRA ticket proposing the addition of a $maxTime or $maxScan query parameter, which sounds like it would help you, so please vote for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2212.

Comment: This option has been implemented and is available in version 2.6

Answer (score 2):

Right now with version `2.6` this is possible. In their [press release](http://www.mongodb.com/press/announcing-mongodb-26-quantum-leap-world%E2%80%99s-fastest-growing-database) you can see the following:

> with MaxTimeMS operators and developers can specify auto-cancellation
>   of queries, providing better control of resource utilization;

Therefore with [MaxTimeMS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) you can specify how much time you allow your query to be executed. For example I do not want a specific query to run more than 200 ms.

```
db.collection.find({
  // my query
}).maxTimeMS(200)
```

What is cool about this, is that you can specify different timeouts for different operations.

**To answer OP's question in the comment**. There is not global setting for this. One reason is that different queries can have different maximum tolerating time. For example you can have query that finds userInfo by it's ID. This is very common operation and should run super fast (otherwise we are doing something wrong). So we can not tolerate it to run longer than 200 ms.

But we also have some aggregation query, which we run once a day. For this operation it is ok to run for 4 seconds. But we can not tolerate it longer than 10 seconds. So we can put 10000 as maxTimeMS.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it as a global setting?

Comment: this is not a server setting, it's an option on the query, so it cannot be set on the server side - only on the application side.

Comment: @IgorEscobar sorry I have not seen your question. From your profile I see that you code in php, so you add this `maxTimeMS` to the end of your query http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.maxtimems.php for every query that you want to shut down, you add this.

Answer (score 2):

There are options available on the *client* side (maxTimeMS starting in 2.6 release).

On the server side, there is no appealing global option, because it would impact all databases and all operations, even ones that the system needs to be long running for internal operation (for example tailing the oplog for replication).  In addition, it may be okay for some of your queries to be long running by design.

The correct way to solve this would be to monitor currently running queries via a script and kill the ones that are long running *and* user/client initiated - you can then build in exceptions for queries that are long running by design, or have different thresholds for different queries/collections/etc.

You can then use [db.currentOp() method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) (in the shell) to see all currently running operations.  The field "secs_running" indicates how long the operation has been running.  Be careful not to kill any long running operations that are not initiated by your application/client - it may be a necessary system operation, like chunk migration in a sharded cluster (as just one example).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is currently no support for killing query by passing time argument. Though in your development side, you can set profiler level to 2. It will log every query that has been issued. From there you can see which queries take how much time. I know its not what you exactly wanted but it helps in getting the insight of what all queries are fat and then in your app logic you can have some way to gracefully handle such cases where those queries might originate. I usually go by this approach and it helps.

Comment: that's not a good idea as keeping profiling on in production will have an effect on performance. it's much better to use currentOp to monitor user operations and killOp to kill the ones that are taking too long.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks for your comment. Didn't knew about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here since I was struggling with the same for a while:

Here is how you can do it in python3
Tested on mongo version 4.0 and pymongo version 3.11.4

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017")
admin_db = client.get_database("admin")

milliseconds_running = 10000

query = [
    {"$currentOp": {"allUsers": True, "idleSessions": True}},
    {
        "$match": {
            "active": True,
            "microsecs_running": {
                "$gte": milliseconds_running * 1000
            },
            "ns": {"$in": ["mydb.collection1", "mydb.collection2"]},
            "op": {"$in": ["query"]},
        }
    },
]

ops = admin_db.aggregate(query)

count = 0

for op in ops:

    admin_db.command({"killOp": 1, "op": op["opid"]})

    count += 1

logging.info("ops found: %d" % count)
```

I wrote a more robust and configurable script for it [here](https://github.com/Kasahs/mongokillslow).
It also has a Dockerfile file in case anyone wants to use this as a container. I am currently using this as a periodicallly running cleanup task.