# MongoDB automated script to kill slow running queries

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have a requirement to kill slow running queries which are running more than 10000ms. Is there any automated way to do that ? Any batch job or function at MongoDB level which can do ?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to your question already exists on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583933/how-to-automatically-kill-slow-mongodb-queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically kill slow MongoDB queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583933/how-to-automatically-kill-slow-mongodb-queries)